# PHP - Search multidimensional associative array by variable

Tags: php

I have this multidimensional associative array:

```
$store = array(
array("id" => 13,"store_id" => 4,"name" => "trumpet","type" => "trumpet567"),
array("id" => 15,"store_id" => 3,"name" => "piano","type" => "piano689"),
array("id" => 33,"store_id" => 1,"name" => "flute","type" => "flute267"),
array("id" => 77,"store_id" => 3,"name" => "violin","type" => "violin324"),
array("id" => 78,"store_id" => 2,"name" => "guitar","type" => "guitar364"),
array("id" => 91,"store_id" => 3,"name" => "accordion","type" => "accordion763"));
```

and a variable:

```
$instrument="guitar";
```

I need to get store_id for $instrument. I've tried so many things but I've got no solution :(

Comment: Why don't you just use a database ?

Answer (score 4):

```
$instrument = 'guitar';
$storeId = null;

foreach ($store as $row) {
    if ($row['name'] == $instrument) {
        $storeId = $row['store_id'];
        break;
    }
}

echo $storeId; // Will echo 2.
```